# Connecting codeigniter to MSSQL 2008 intermittent connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I've currently got a development LAMP stack (turnkey) running on a VM, I'm using codeigniter as my MVC framework and am using MSSQL 2008 at the backend on the LAN.

Most of the time, this works fine, however I intermittently get the below error when loading a page:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: Lslite

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

Refreshing the page normally resolves this.

My Database.php config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sserver';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'Password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'Lslite';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

There is no issue with the database, it is the backend for a .Net application, similarly there are no issues with the credentials, they are shared with the .Net application.

Any pointers as to tracking down the problem would be appreciated, I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: Hey Kyle, If it is connecting ever then I would say this is not a CI or php issue and I dont think you will have much luck here (mainly programming questions). It sounds to me like a networking/server setup/vm issue. You should try asking on http://superuser.com/ they are better on these type of questions in my experience. One small suggestion I can give is to get some sort of query/access logging on your sql server, to see if a login attempt is being received, i think this works for ms sql http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ Also there is dba.stackexchange.com but its aimed at db pros so try SU 1st

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I do however believe that this is a codeigniter issue. I have non-codeigniter code running fine without any connection issues from the same VM with the same credentials. Since this appears to be a problem with my implementation of a php framework, how is this off-topic?

Comment: If it is connecting intermittently, it's not a problem with the db config in CI. So I really dont think the issue is here. The only Ci related thing it could be is a problem with the way you have written one of your queries. Perhaps incorrect syntax in a query which only runs intermittently is throwing the db. Check if the problem is happening running a particular query. Either way I dont think this question was going to help you. See if you can see a pattern in when this is happening by checking the server logs. +1 for harsh downvote

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me and for the upvote :) CI is stable in the live environment so you're right, the issue must be in the environment somewhere, flakey virtual machine. Just frustrating since there's nothing in any of the logs. Thanks again for you help.